# Trouble installing a Grapher (install.package command) on Debian

Tags: debian, installation, r

I'm trying to install Grapher from https://grapher.network/docs/install

The V8 library install is fine, works great. But the second line to get Grapher is throwing an error. According to the doc it says to input:

```
install.packages("remotes", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")remotes::install_github('JohnCoene/grapher', dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```

But that throws an error. I've never seen an install that wasn't "apt install" or "dpkg" so this install format has me stumped. Any explanation of this install format would be great. Thank you

Comment: What error does it throw? Have you done web searches for that error yet? What did you learn from those searches?